# Validación de input date con javascript

Tags: javascript, date, validación

necesito hacer la validación de un input de tipo date, para que garantice que no sea una fecha incorrecta, según leí se puede hacer con una regex, por lo que implementé una, sin embargo, todas las fechas que ejecute salen como "incorrectas". Les dejo mi código

````
    let fechaUs= document.getElementById("fecha");
    let regex=/^(?:(?:(0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])[/](0?[1-9]|1[0-2])|(29|30)[/](0?[13-9]|1[0-2])|(31)[/](0?[13578]|1[02]))[/](0{2,3}[1-9]|0{1,2}[1-9]\d|0?[1-9]\d{2}|[1-9]\d{3})|(29)[/](0?2)[/](\d{1,2}(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:0?[48]|[13579][26]|[2468][048])00))$/;
    if(fechaUs.value!="")
    {
        if (regex.test(fechaUs.value)) {
            alert("Fecha correcta");
            return true;
        }else{
            alert("Fecha incorrecta");
            return false;
        }
    }else{
        alert("Debe seleccionar una fecha de nacimiento");
        return false;
    }
}```
````

Comment: Hola Zenich, validar una fecha con un regex no es una buena idea, te aconsejo que uses un objeto fecha, y verificar que lo puedes crear.

Comment: @MarcePuente Gracias, ya logré hacerlo, te lo agradezco infinitamente, saludos

Comment: Un placer colaborar contigo.